# except: block running even though try: ran successfully

Tags: python

This code is to print the most-recently-modified directory. A directory with no sub-dirs will throw and exception, so I put it in a try-except block. The code in both sections is running!?

```
  try:
  newest = max( [x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(x)], key = os.path.getmtime)
  print(newest)
  exit()
except:
  print("No directories found!")
  exit()
```

I see this output ('bin' is the correct newest sub-directory). The print from try: and except: has executed.

```
bin
No directories found!
```

What'd I miss?  Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: `exit()` could be raising an exception

Comment: That's *exactly* what `exit` does when called: it raises `SystemExit`. This is why you don't use bare `except`. Use `except Exception` to avoid caching the "control-flow" exceptions `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `StopIteration`.

Comment: `max` raises a `ValueError` if called with an empty sequence. So `except ValueError:` handles that, but gives you a chance to debug any other, unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exit() is raising an exception. Try:

```
try:
    newest = max( [x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(x)], key = os.path.getmtime)
    print(newest)
except Exception:
    print("No directories found!")
finally:
    exit()
```